# php Mysql Error unknown id

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I'm trying to make a blog in PHP/MySQL and have got 2 tables

- posts (id int(6),cat_id int(3),title varchar(255),contents text)
- categories (cat_id int(11),name varchar(24)).

I am getting an error - 'Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'' when I try to run edit function.

```
<?php
include_once('resources/init.php');

$post=get_posts($_GET['id']); 
if(isset($_POST['title'],$_POST['contents'],$_POST['category']))
{
    $title=trim($_POST['title']);   
    $contents=trim($_POST['contents']); 

    edit_post($_GET['id'],$title,$contents,$_POST['category']);

    header("Location:index.php?id=$post[0]['posts.id']");
    die();
}
?>
```

Here is the edit function -

```
function edit_post($id,$title,$contents,$category)
{
    $id=(int)$id;
    $title=mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $category=(int)$category;

    $contents=mysql_real_escape_string($contents);

    mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET cat_id=  {$category},
                                  title='{$title}',
                                  contents='{$contents}' 
                  WHERE id={$id}");
}
```

You might need to refer get_posts function-

```
function get_posts($id=null,$cat_id=null){
    $posts=array();
    $query=("SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.cat_id AS category_id,  
                    title, contents, 
                    categories.name AS name
             FROM posts 
                INNER JOIN categories ON categories.cat_id = posts.cat_id");

    if (isset($id)) {
        $id=(int)$id;
        $query .= " WHERE posts.id={$id}";
    }
    if(isset($cat_id)) {
        $cat_id=(int)$cat_id;
        $query .=" WHERE categories.cat_id={$cat_id}";  
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY posts.id DESC";
    $query = mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $posts[]=$row;  
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

I have referred the solutions provided for this type of error on the site but it wasn't helpful for my case. Please help.

Comment: Check what you are sending into the `edit_post($id,$title,$contents,$category)` function on the `$id` parameter, If its not an integer then casting it to `(int)` may destroy any value at all

Comment: You also check all the other fields exist using `isset()` but you do not check that the `$_GET['id']` exists in that same way

Comment: The error indicates its an issue with one of your queries. Please include your table structures in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if Id is set in your url, try this approach

```
include_once('resources/init.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['contents'],$_POST['category']))
{
    $post=get_posts($_GET['id']); 
    $title=trim($_POST['title']);   
    $contents=trim($_POST['contents']); 

    edit_post($_GET['id'],$title,$contents,$_POST['category']);

    $id = $post[0]['posts.id'];
    echo $id;
    header("Location:index.php?id=".$id);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run your first script directly, it should be runned with form submit with id input inside.